# why do I keep getting an error about moveObject is an undeclared identifier?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    moveObjectTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(moveObject) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]


-(void)moveObject 

    image.center = CGPointMake(image.center.x, image.center.y +5);
}
```

Comment: Could you verify your syntax above?  Missing some brackets and such...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a couple curly braces.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    moveObjectTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(moveObject) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]
}

-(void)moveObject 
{
    image.center = CGPointMake(image.center.x, image.center.y +5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `moveObject` is not declared in your .h file (or declared in an interface block before `viewDidLoad`) then the compiler has no way to know about it at that point.

So add it to your .h file.

Your other option is to put the moveObject method (implementation) above your viewDidLoad method.  This may be preferred if you don't want the .h file to reveal moveObject, but you can also use an additional @interface block in your .m file if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to declare the method in the header file, given the syntax errors in the questions are not there in the original source.

In the .h file:

```
- (void)moveObject;
```